# Console log spam on iOS 11

Tags: ios, logging

I'm trying to get some info out of the console logs and I can see a endless spam of this line:

```
Oct 16 10:24:15 Name-iPad SpringBoard(UIKit)[53] <Notice>: *** _applyBackdropViewSettings error: image must be backed by a CGImage: <UIImage: 0x1c04a33c0> size {1024, 768} orientation 0 scale 1.000000
```

It never stops, I have no idea what that is or where it's coming from, does anyone know?.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I discovered what was going on, the wallpaper used in the device apparently had some issues, after changing it to a default one the problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

Reboot your iPhone will solve this problem, try it.